# Web Server CPU/Memory Resource LImited as a result of multiple ajax calls to PHP script

Tags: php, ajax, memory, cpu, file-get-contents

I'm hosting a website with Webhostingpad, and I'm running into an issue.  As my homepage loads, I am currently making 8 concurrent ajax calls to a php script that returns content being used for the homepage.  The 8 ajax calls are calling a file called run.php.  The job of this file is just to call a function from a class called amazon, that is defined in another file called amazon.php.

This is the URL being called 8 times via ajax.  The only difference between the 8 calls is the query string:

http://my-domain.com/run.php?f=getItemsById&arg=id:B0043OYFKU,B001JKTTVQ,B004Y9D90Q,B003S516XO,B002XQ1YTK,B003V265QW,B00121UVU0,B004EDYQUE,B000P22TIY,B000E7WHLY

As you can see, I'm passing the function name in the "f" parameter of the url.

The run.php file looks like this:

```
require_once('amazon.php');

$function_name = $_REQUEST['f'];
$arg_parameter = $_REQUEST['arg'];

$arg_tmp = explode(";", $arg_parameter);
$arg_array = array();
foreach($arg_tmp as $key_value_pair){
    $exploded = explode(':', $key_value_pair);
    $key = $exploded[0];
    $value = $exploded[1];
    $arg_array[$key] = $value;
}

$amazon = new amazon();
echo $amazon->$function_name($arg_array);
```

As you can see, this file is simply calling a function from amazon.php and echoing the result so I can use it in the callback of the ajax function.

Here's the relevant code from amazon.php regarding the `getItemsById()` function:

```
class amazon {

    private $url;
    private $accessKey = 'AKIAISJ2OHTBA888311SD';
    private $secretAccessKey = 'RM8EG61w3dLwjymtAEVdfsdiesd883711lskdf';

    function __construct(){
        $this->url = 'http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?Service=AWSECommerceService&AWSAccessKeyId=' . $this->accessKey . '&AssociateTag=global-18&Version=2011-08-01';
    }

    public function getItemsById($args = array()){

        $itemIds = $args['id'];

        $url = $this->url;
        $url .= '&Operation=ItemLookup';
        $url .= '&ItemId=' . $itemIds;
        $url .= '&ResponseGroup=Images,Small,Offers,VariationSummary,EditorialReview';

        $signedUrl = $this->amazonSign($url, $this->secretAccessKey);
        $returned_xml = file_get_contents($signedUrl);
        return $returned_xml;

    }
}
```

As you can see above, this function is calling a URL for amazon.com's API, and returning XML using PHP's `file_get_contents()` function.  My issue is that some of the ajax calls made to run.php are successfully exexcuted, while others are getting HTTP 500 Internal Server Errors.  When I run this on my local server, it works fine.  When I run it on a development server at my office, it works fine.  However, I consistently see this issue on my Webhostingpad server.  Some of the ajax calls return HTTP 500 errors.

I've spoken to Webhostingpad support and the only insight they have offered me is that I'm exceeding my CPU/Memory resource limit.  The error logs from the server seem to confirm that:

> [Tue Feb 19 21:36:39 2013] [error] [client 68.174.126.115] (12)Cannot
>   allocate memory: couldn't create child process: /opt/suphp/sbin/suphp
>   for /home/my-server/public_html/my-domain.com/run.php, referer:
>   http://my-domain.com/

My question for the community is if anything is standing out here as obviously memory intensive?  I feel like what I'm doing isn't that out of the oridnary, so I'm trying to figure out if I should be focusing on optimizing my scripts, or if I should simply be looking for another hosting provider.

Comment: too many sites on one shared server is my guess.

Comment: Do the calls have to be concurrent? Or can you simply execute the first AJAX call, wait until it completes, store the local data in a data structure, execute the second call, rinse, repeat?  The object in the browser which executes the Ajax call will let you know once it completes.

Comment: Thanks @kermit.  I previously had the ajax calls working syncronously (I know that's frowned upon, which is why I changed it), but that basically mimicked the same behavior you are describing where one call would only occurr after the other completed.  The main issue there was that it was significanly slower then making all 8 calls at the same time and using a deferred object to act when they are all complete.

Comment: Well... the other option would be to send up all the required data in one Ajax call so there is only one instance of the executing PHP script. Implement a singleton pattern for your classes (so that only once instance is created - basically this involves a private constructor and a function which checks to see if the class is created. If it is, a reference to the class is returned, and if not the class is constructed and a reference is returned).  A one-shot deal should reduce overhead I think, instead of 8 separate calls.

Comment: Yeesh - the singleton pattern used to be on the PHP.net site, but now it's only in German. But the second example - the important one - is in English. Don't know what's going on there: http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.patterns.php - Don't need to worry about implementing the clone or wakeup methods just yet. Those are nice but not necessary for testing.

Answer (score 0):

If executing the AJAX requests synchronously is not an option, you could still do something about the memory consumption of the PHP scripts. Currently the PHP script takes the entire XML that is returned from amazon in memory before it is echoed to the client. If the XML is large and you do it 8 times concurrently, running out of memory is not so strange.

A solution would be to do the request to amazon with cURL and use the cURL option CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION to echo the results to the client. This way, you could make the amazon.php script stream the result XML to the client and it won't use as much memory.

Example amazon.php code:

```
<?
function writeCallback($handle, $data)
{
    echo $data;    
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    return strlen($data);
}

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'writeCallback');

ob_start(); // start output buffer
curl_exec($ch); // commence streaming
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion Matthijs. I just want to make sure I fully understand what's happning here because I've implemented it as you suggested and it didn't make a difference as far as the memory errors I'm receiving. Is there a reason you're using a callback function that echos the data rather than using the option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` and setting the output of curl_exec equal to a variable. Also, why is the callback function returning `strlen($data)`? Basically, I'm trying to understand exactly how this is supposed to be working because currently it's not making a difference.

Comment: The main reason to do it this way is to **stream** the data that you receive from amazon and not take it all into memory at once. If you check the documentation for CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, you will see that CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION allows you to do just that.

Comment: One important part of all this is that you do not buffer the data in the writeCallback, because that defeats the purpose. You have to send each piece of the data out unbuffered. It may require that you call `ob_flush()` after every echo. I have updated the code above to reflect this. 

BUT, this may still not work, because your webserver may also buffer the output, even though you PHP script does not. This could happen when Apaches mod_deflate is enabled for instance.

Comment: Thanks again Matthijs. This also doesn't seem to be helping which you pointed out it still may not.  I looked at the docs for CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php but I don't see anything about **streaming** as you suggested.  If there is any more insight you can offer, I would really appreciate it, but it's looking like I may have to upgrade my hosting plan to have dedicated memory and CPU resources.  Also, could you explain why your writeCallback function is returning `strlen($data)`?  Is this just a convention of some kind?

Comment: The docs from php.net for CURLOPT_WRITEFUNTION below. See in bold the answer to your last question:

CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION  The name of a callback function where the callback function takes two parameters. The first is the cURL resource, and the second is a string with the data to be written. The data must be saved by using this callback function. **It must return the exact number of bytes written or the transfer will be aborted with an error.**